# React native authentication issue

Tags: react-native, authentication

I have a couple of routes in react-native-expo and I was wondering if there is a way I can navigate between them. Now see. one of the routes is the login route and the other ones are the routes the user gets access to once they authorize themselves.

```
{authorized ? (
          <>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Reddit" component={Reddit} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Messages" component={Messages} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Video" component={VideoPage} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        )}
```

when I when the login succeeds in the login route I cannot redirect the user to the home page. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just have two separate navigators for each authentication state.

Also make `authorized` a state that will force a render if it changes.